# How to resolve error in k3s installation :Job for k3s.service failed

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, rancher, k3s

I am facing problem in installing K3s on Ubuntu instance and connecting mysql AWS RDS with the master node . I have made 1 master node and 3 worker node .When I try to execute the following commands below I get error. Please help me with this .I checked the inbound and outbound rules in security group which is attached to RDS and EC2 instance but it works fine . Please Help !!!!

```
Job for k3s.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status k3s.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

**INSTALLATION COMMANDS after making RDS mysql dataabse with db name k3s**

```
export K3S_DATASTORE_ENDPOINT='mysql://k3s:<xxxdbpasswordxxx>@tcp(k3s-cluster-db.cz2c5bol8r6l.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306)/k3s'
```

```
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | INSTALL_K3S_EXEC="--write-kubeconfig=/home/ubuntu/.kube/config  --write-kubeconfig-mode=644" sh -
```

**ERROR :**

[image]

**INBOUND RULES**

[image]

**OUTBOUND RULES**
[image]

**systemctl status k3s.service**
[image]

**journalctl -xe**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your command seems to have two issues:

```
INSTALL_K3S_EXEC=“—write-kubeconfig=/home/ubuntu/.kube/config  --write-kubeconfig-mode=644”
```

- using `“` instead of `"` can be misinterpreted by the shell
- an option like `—write-kubeconfig` should use `--` (as in `—-write-kubeconfig`)

Since the error message is `flag provided but not defined: --write-kube-config` (and has `--`), it is possible the above is just a font/display issue.
In that case, check if this is an [option order issue as described here](https://github.com/rancher/rke2/issues/2603#issuecomment-1067434942=).

Comment: curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | INSTALL_K3S_EXEC="--write-kubeconfig=/home/ubuntu/.kube/config  --write-kubeconfig-mode=644" sh -    >> I used this command   it gives the same error still   ........

Comment: Even before I used the same command ...copy pasting from notepad to stackoverflow changed the syntax ....

Comment: @Ayush OK I thought so. On which Ubuntu version are you?

Comment: AWS EC2 image instance -ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64-server-20220610

Comment: I am following this tutorial link :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zSlRUMm36n8

Comment: @Ayush For testing, try https://sysadmins.co.za/3-node-multimaster-k3s-kubernetes-cluster-with-mysql/, which uses `--write-kubeconfig-mode 644` instead of `--write-kubeconfig`.

Comment: ok let me try ...

Comment: Can you help me editing this --> curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | INSTALL_K3S_EXEC="--write-kubeconfig-mode 644 --token secret-01010101-xabcdefx --tls-san k3s.mydomain.com --node-taint k3s-controlplane=true:NoExecute" sh -s - server --datastore-endpoint=
“mysql://k3s:<xxxdbpasswordxxx>@tcp(k3s-cluster-db.cz2c5bol8r6l.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306)/k3s”

Comment: is this part--->xabcdefx --tls-san k3s.mydomain.com required ??

Comment: I ran  this command but it gives the same error >>>root@ip-172-31-94-90:~# curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | INSTALL_K3S_EXEC="--write-kubeconfig-mode 644 --token secret-01010101-xabcdefx --tls-san k3s.mydomain.com --node-taint k3s-controlplane=true:NoExecute" sh -s - server --datastore-endpoint="mysql://k3s:xxx<pass>xxx@tcp(k3s-cluster-db.cz2c5bol8r6l.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306)/k3s"

Comment: @Ayush OK. I don't have much more beside looking for other similar tutorials.